# unit 'TeeJPEG' not found in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart

I am using Delphi 10.3 and the TeeChart is V2016 VCL. I added uses TeeJPEG, but it can not find this unit, anybody knows why? TeExport, Teeprocs, TeEngine all seem fine. Does my Teechart not support TeeJPEG?? Or how to use this TeeJPEG in uses?? Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK that one is only included in the Pro edition.

Comment: That unit is part of the _Export to picture (PNG, GIF, JPEG, TIFF, SVG, PDF, VML)_ feature which only comes with TeeChart Pro. See: [TeeChart Feature Matrix](https://www.steema.com/feature_matrix/vcl)